# Displaying data in the tableView with custom view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-view

In my app, I'm having a tableview, which I access using section and not by row.
I have used custom views on section section, the custom view contains few labels

In my cellForRow at index,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
viewOrderPage=[[ViewOrder alloc]init];

static NSString * cellIdentifier=@"Mytable";
UITableViewCell * cell;



if(cell==nil)
{
    cell=[contentTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    viewOrderPage=[[ViewOrder alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 60)];
    viewOrderPage.tag=111;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:viewOrderPage];

}
else
{
    viewOrderPage=(ViewOrder *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
}


viewOrderPage.productName.text=@"aaa";

return cell;
}
```

But the value is not getting displayed in the cell.

```
viewOrderPage is the object of the customview(ViewOrder) and productName is a label in the view
```

Comment: you should create a proper UITableView subclass

Comment: can u please elaborate

Comment: can u just search for it? covered deeply by apples docs and certainly thousands of blog posts and stack overflow posts.

Comment: u said, proper subclass, that means?

Comment: a real subclass. not a UITableViewCell with just altering the view hierarchy

Comment: 3291 hits: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uitableviewcell+subclass

Comment: or use prototype classes from storyboard.

Comment: no, i am not using story board

Comment: than use subclass. only sane option

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier=@"Mytable";
    ViewOrder * cell= (ViewOrder *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewOrder" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=self.vieworder;
    }

NSString * str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"%@",str);

    cell.productName.text=str;


    return cell;
    }
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: but the str is getting printed in log